# Sort on look up in mongo using java

Tags: java, mongodb

I want to sort the array return by lookup in Mongo and then use projection on that data in java. Can someone suggest how to do that ?

Sample code:

```
Mongoclient.getDatabase(db).get collection(order request).aggregate(Arrays.asList(new Document("$lookup",new Document( "from", "order").append("localfield","Id").append("foreignField","Id").append("as", "orders")),
new Document("$lookup",new Document( "from", "Inventory").append("localfield","Id").append("foreignField","Id").append("as", "inventory")),
new Document("$project", new Document ("I'd",0L).append("order date", new Document("$arrayElementAt", Arrays.asList("$orders.date",0L)))
```

I want to have max order date return by lookup on orders

Comment: Hard to begin answering this question without more information. Can you provide sample input documents and the output you expect from them?